# what's mean "the request cannot be passed to the next server if nginx already started sending the request body"

Tags: nginx

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_request_buffering

i can not understanding  "When buffering is disabled, the request body is sent to the proxied server immediately as it is received. In this case, the request cannot be passed to the next server if nginx already started sending the request body."

what's  mean "the request cannot be passed to the next server if nginx already started sending the request body"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a service with [multiple upstream servers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#upstream), possibly for load balancing or resilience, and one of the upstream servers fail while Nginx is sending the request body to it, Nginx may try to use another server.

But it can only try another server if it has a complete copy of the original request body (i.e. request buffering enabled) or the client has not started sending the request body yet.